Starting MongoD but gives an error on ArchLinux
When I write mongod in the terminal It gives me this error.
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.518+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.519+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":21},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.519+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.520+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.520+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.520+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.520+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":7091600, "ctx":"main","msg":"Starting TenantMigrationAccessBlockerRegistry"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.521+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":15524,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"matrix"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.521+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"7.0.11","gitVersion":"f451220f0df2b9dfe073f1521837f8ec5c208a8c","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.521+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"NAME=\"Arch Linux\"","version":"Kernel 6.9.4-arch1-1"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.521+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.521+04:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.521+04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/asio/asio_transport_layer.cpp","line":1202}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-18T07:13:44.521+04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}

I couldn't do anything, bacause I am new to databases and arch, Also I couldn't find any specific solution to this problem.

The error message in the log is "Failed to unlink socket file" . Here is a post with some suggested solutions for MongoDB and Linux: 'Failed to unlink socket file" error in MongoDB 3.0. Further, you can also search the net with the search string: "mongodb  'Failed to unlink socket file'"

Check if mongod is already running. It may start automatically as a service.

This issue seems to be related to the sockets that mongodb requires. By default mongodb, runs on port 27017, which it currently isn't able to.
This is usually happens if you don't run the command with sudo. It could also happen if port 27107 is already blocked, perhaps by another instance of mongodb.
However, because the error says {"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}, it's probably an issue with permissions.

Thanks A lot my friend you helped me very much I was sitiing there trying to fix it and all it took was to run it with sudo. Thanks man!
